# Yii session resetting on redirect

Tags: php, session, yii, session-variables

I have the following code to identify a session for language_id OR set a session if a $_GET varaiable is passed. The following function `detectLanguage()` is called in my component Controller.php file inside `init();`

```
private function detectLanguage()
{
  if(isset($_GET['language_code']) && !empty($_GET['language_code'])){
    $language = Language::model()->find(array(
      'condition' => 'iso_code = :iso_code',
      'params' => array(':iso_code' => $_GET['language_code']),
    ));
    if($language != NULL){
        Yii::app()->session['language_id'] = $language->id;
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);
    } else {
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);
    }
  } else {
    $currentLang = (isset(Yii::app()->session['language_id']))? Yii::app()->session['language_id'] : 1;
    if(Language::model()->find(array('condition' => "id = :id AND country_id = :country_id",'params' => array(':id' => $currentLang, 'country_id' => $this->country_details['ID'])))){
      return $currentLang;
    } else {
      Yii::app()->session['language_id'] = 1;
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

When I go to the URL ...?language_code=ru, it successfully sets the session and redirects to the referrer URL, but when I then refresh the page, it resets the language_id session to 1.

I do not understand, as far as I can see, my logic in this function is fine.

EDIT: Also tried with cookies and there is no other code interacting with these SESSION variables which could be interferring.

Comment: Can you give details about what `$this->country_details['ID']` does?  It could be the cause for your if statement failing, leading to `Yii::app()->session['language_id'] = 1;` being executed.

Comment: Returns an integer like 4. It's just an object property set in another function.

Comment: If the logic is fine, then my only conclusion is that your Language active record does not return any results for your input parameters, thus not running `return $currentLang;` and executing the `else` statement instead.  As a quick and dirty test, try throwing an exception in the else portion and see if your page refresh hits it.